# Array of dictionaries to a single array of dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript array as

```
arr = [{"class":"a"},{"sub_class":"b"},{"category":"c"},{"sub_category":"d"}]
```

I want a new array as:

```
new_arr = [{"class":"a", "sub_class":"b", "category":"c", "sub_category":"d"}]
```

Is it possible to do this in Javascript without using a for loop to iterate through `arr`?

Comment: Why is it still an array if you only have one element in it?

Comment: Because I might need to push new dictionaries to the array later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`:

```js
const array = [{
  "class": "a"
}, {
  "sub_class": "b"
}, {
  "category": "c"
}, {
  "sub_category": "d"
}]

const mergedObject = Object.assign({}, ...array);

// And put in an Array if that was intentional
const newArray = [mergedObject];

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to merge objects. You could either use a spread operator or `Object.assign`. I don't see the point of having a single object inside an array. Considering your requirements you could do:

```
const merged = arr.reduce((list, curr) => {
   return Object.assign({}, list, curr);
}, {});

const newArr = [merged];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var arr = [{"class":"a"},{"sub_class":"b"},{"category":"c"},{"sub_category":"d"}];
var res=[];
var res1=[];
res=Object.assign(...arr);
res1.push(res);

console.log("Result: ",res1);
```

Comment: Just be aware that this mutates the first object in `arr`, which you may or may not care about. Passing `{}` as the first element will make sure you're creating a new object and are assigning to that.